# Can questions directly related to an active tag be off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

[docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) is a quite active tag on SO (11k followers, 21k questions), but multiple times, when asking a question about Docker API with "Docker" mentioned in title and the [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) tag, my questions have received a "close" vote (reason : "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User. ")

I've had the same problems with [wso2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2) (856 followers, 6.8k questions).

So far, I've had no question closed but it may eventually happen, so what can I do about it ? Can a question directly related to an active tag be off-topic ?

I see 2 solutions :

- The SO "off-topic" rules are updated to precise a question directly related to an active tag has to be considered on-topic
- The tag related to system or middleware get removed and an other "stackexchange" website is pointed to manage these subjects (Actually they are "DevOps" subjects, but sometimes more "Ops" than "Dev".)

Comment: I sometimes see this close reason when it’s absolutely not appropriate… it appears to be [the case here as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42701332/4642212). I don’t know anything about Docker, so I can’t really tell you how to improve the question.

Comment: I don't think a closing vote is about "improving the question", it's about closing it and maybe transferring it to an other Stackexchange site.

Comment: Not really… it’s a rare case that a question gets closed, just because it actually belongs on another site. Most close reasons and most close votes are indicators for questions that need improvement (e.g. too broad → limit the scope; no MCVE → create one; unclear what you’re asking → clarify it, etc.).

Comment: Ok but the question you are pointing to has a close vote which is not for "too broad", "MCVE" or "unclear what you’re asking", you can click on "close vote" to see it's for "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User. " as I mention above.

Comment: When docker question are not off topics, they are too broad. Many of the top question on this tag are off topics, from my point of view. But some of them have really cool answer. So I always vote close.

Comment: Pierre, you have 527 reputation, you can vote for close from 3000, so what are u talking about ?

Comment: I mean flag as off topic...

Comment: Tag activity just doesn't have anything to do with it.  The [windows] tag is very active, attracts a ton of off-topic questions.  [docker] and [wso2] are certainly risky, they are apps.  Whether you actually use the api in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42701332/17034) is, well, not so obvious.  Doesn't exactly look like it, so a single CV is not surprising.  It takes 5 so you are still a long way from getting your knuckles rapped.

Comment: Yes my meta question was precisely about tags. I thought they were manually created and would be removed if they were related to mostly off-topic (non programming) question. I'm not defending the fact that Docker or WSO2 are "programming" related, most question about Docker and WSO2 WON'T be about "programming" but since they are active not removed tags, any precise question related to these tags should be considered as on-topic right ?

Comment: @Tristan "why is Docker named Docker" is precise,and about the tag... Doesn't make it on topic. Extreme example I know,but the point stands. "About an active and on topic tag" isn't enough to make a question on topic

Comment: If Docker was a programming tool or language, "why is Docker named Docker" could be on topic though, if the name put some light on the tool purpose (like Scala). The point is "Docker" is not a programming tool, find me a few question which are on-topic (programming-related) concerning docker. So either docker-related questions are accepted here and the tag remains, either the existence of the tag is really misleading.

Comment: No, asking why something is named something is NOT on topic.  Questions on SO have to involve writing software, or using tools in the furtherance of writing software.

Comment: *So either docker-related questions are accepted here and the tag remains, either the existence of the tag is really misleading.* Or you have a misunderstanding of the purpose of tags on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "Or you have a misunderstanding of the purpose of tags on Stack Overflow." Sure, but if you are right, the way u say it is not making me improve in any way. It's not even the purpose which is important, it's why they have been created. I guess they've been created because questions about these tags are "on-topic", or the creation request would have been refused.

Comment: The reason the tag exists is to handle questions about using code to interact with Docker, or using Docker to run code. We similarly have tags for IDEs; there are on-topic questions that make sense to tag that way; there are also questions that are specifically about the IDE (and not about **using it for code**) that are off topic.

Comment: I honestly don’t understand what you are trying to say. It seems like you are saying that *any* question related to tags with activity is automatically on-topic. That is frankly ridiculous - we wouldn’t have any off-topic questions by that definition.